# Why is there a SignalR web socket connection in a barebones Blazor WebAssembly project?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a new barebones Blazor WebAssembly project and just inspecting the initial downloads and latency that's expected. However I was not expecting a `SignalR` web socket connection as it's a client app, and not the server version of Blazor which uses `SignalR` at its core. Why is my Blazor WAZM project using `SignalR`? I thought it might be to load all of the initial .NET runtime resources faster vs. `http` but that doesn't appear to be the case, and where is this configured please? I'm not going to change it, but would like to understand it fully as this wasn't what I was expecting.

Network output:
[image]
Physical call in trace:

`Request URL (note: **browserLinkSignalR**): ws://localhost:60525/179d598a93704694ae130b00995965d7/browserLinkSignalR/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAH1UFWPLRq0iqQHflT2xYeQAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAC67QHq8stecCuv3CRLw1AJAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAM%2FXIiNXL8Ba%2Bbl%2B5TYEiBgoAAAAkRXf3%2FgcWA2ic3QvQvJev9egqIHVTj8mg3jjhrlyVS8DgPhicYXbCxQAAAAdkzbeua8vsSifbfffxqMnU%2BVSFA%3D%3D&requestUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7188%2F&browserName=&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F105.0.0.0+Safari%2F537.36&browserIdKey=window.browserLink.initializationData.browserId&browserId=04a2-38b0&tid=7`

Comment: This is a feature of visual studio for debugging purposes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I just realized this, came back to this question, and you validated it. Makes total sense for hot reloading features from the IDE, even Angular does something similar in the CLI. I was initially thrown off because I was fixated on the whole, 'client doesn't use SignalR.' Please add an answer to this question with your information, and I'll mark it as such. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The websocket connection is created by [Browser Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0), a Visual Studio feature that uses SignalR to create a communication channel between Visual Studio and the browser. It is used for client-side development.